# getting values from a dynamic href links

Tags: javascript, href

hello friends i am trying to get value from a dynamic href link . in which the three values which i pass through the href changes . actally the href is a part of image . i am getting 7 images from database . it means there are 7 href in total . so here is my problem , even if i try to extract the value from the href . only the value of the fst href is displayed in alert . here is my jquery code. for eg . i click on 3rd image then also values of the first href link is displayed .can anyone help me out ?

```
var a = document.getElementById('plzx');

var parts = a.search.slice(1).split('&');

var table = {};

for( var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++ ) {
    var pair = parts[i].split('=');
    table[pair[0]] = pair[1];
}


var id = table.id;
var a =table.a;
var pic =table.pic;
```

and here is my gallery code sample by which i getting values in href dynamically

```
<li>
    <a href="<?php echo $pic;?>?id=<?php echo $id;?>&a=<?php echo $srcwidth;?>&pic=<?php echo $picID;?>" data-title="hi" data-desc=" " data-rel="group2" data-bw="<?php echo $pic;?>"  class="lightbox" id="plzx" >                         
        <img src="<?php echo $pic;?>"  width="160" height="160" title="Click To View"/> 
    </a>                                        
</li>
```

my php code .after being executed

```
         <a id="plzx" class="lightbox" data-bw="uploads/1452243951jatin.png" data-rel="group2" data-desc=" " data-title="hi" href="uploads/1452243951jatin.png?id=3&amp;a=796&amp;pic=4">

                    <span style="position: relative;" class="tp-lightbox-element">
            <img width="160" height="160" title="Click To View" src="uploads/1452243951jatin.png">
       </span>
       </a>
```

Comment: you know there is no jQuery here right?

Comment: sry it was a part of my jquery file . yes its simple javascript . i aceept answers if they are helpfull in any way friend . i think this is what everyone do? right?

Comment: Could we see the page source after the PHP code has executed?

Comment: @paislee You know jquery is not a necessity right?

Comment: @SomeshMukherjee not my point. it was tagged as such, and the question  reads: "here is my jquery code"

Comment: getElementById only gets one element(whose id matches plzxx). You cannot have two elements wiht same id. It will always match the first element only

Comment: @SomeshMukherjee then how to get those 3 values ?

Comment: You need to add an extra class and use jquery. I'll post an edit. Might be better, if you can make a jsfiddle so I can happily edit away

Comment: @SomeshMukherjee i tried adding an extra class , and get it value by val() in jquery but it says undefined .

Comment: GIve me 10 minutes. m makin the jsfiddle

Comment: You mention that only the first one is displayed in the `alert` but your code doesn't show an `alert`

Answer (score 0):

well.as far as i know unfortunately A tags cannot be identified independently..this can be avoided using divs for each A tags.

or you can get the list of all A tags from the page like this..

```
var lnk = td.getElementsByTagName('a')[0]
var src=lnk.href
```

Answer (score 0):

​    `$('.classname​​​​​​​​​​​').click(function(){
     a=this;
     var parts = a.search.slice(1).split('&');
     var table = {};`

```
 for( var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++ ) {
 var pair = parts[i].split('=');
 table[pair[0]] = pair[1];
 }

var id = table.id;
 alert(id);
var a =table.a;
 var pic =table.pic;
return false;
 });
```

​Check out this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yBJ6j/

Comment: also, if you want to use dom methods, it can be done too. Its just a little tiresome

Comment: friend i dnt want to use the click function as i m using this value in a lightbox .

Comment: where were u running the code originally? Did you not attach an event handler? I mean when does this code get called? What do you want to do with the ids and all. If you state your exact purpose, we could help u

Comment: my lightbox width depend upon the value of a . and if u use click function then when the lightbox opens , and i use next button to view next pic , then the lightbox would have no width as there is no CLICK.

Comment: So when do exactly you want to use this code? What should trigger it and what's the purpose of it? Perhaps, this is better done on chat